# 2 SQL Updates in 1 statement

Tags: sql, sql-update

Im trying to do something like the following:

```
UPDATE table SET fieldA='valueA' WHERE id='id1', SET fieldB='valueB' WHERE id='id2';
```

But cant seem to get it to work. Is there a way of doing this, or will I need to use two separate SQL commands?

Comment: While am sure there's some convoluted SQL that can be written to do what you want, it's best to just use 2 update statements for several reasons. The first of which is that you want to be able to read your own code without getting a headache!

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412101/is-it-possible-to-perform-multiple-updates-with-a-single-update-sql-statement

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you *really* need to do it in one statement, you can use this:

```
UPDATE table 
    SET fieldA = case when id = 'id1' then 'valueA' else fieldA end, 
        fieldB = case when id = 'id2' then 'valueB' else fieldB end
WHERE id in ('id1', 'id2');
```

But for clarity (and thus maintainability), it would be much better to use two statements.

Comment: Many thanks for answering my question! I am trying to reduce the number of SQL calls in my code to improve speed, I am willing to sacrifice a bit of clarity to achieve this!

Answer (score 2):

This is best done as 2 different UPDATE statements, because you have 2 different WHERE clauses:

```
UPDATE table SET fieldA='valueA' WHERE id='id1'
UPDATE table SET fieldB='valueB' WHERE id='id2'
```

Comment: It doesn't. If there is an appropriate index it is *better* to do it as two updates, but it *can* be done as a single statement if it is *really* necessary (and so yield a single scan if there is no appropriate index).

Answer (score 1):

```
MERGE INTO YourTable
   USING ( VALUES ( 'id1', 'valueA', NULL ), 
                  ( 'id2', NULL, 'valueB' ) )              
      AS source ( id, fieldA , fieldB )
         ON YourTable.id = source.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET fieldA = COALESCE(source.fieldA, YourTable.fieldA), 
          fieldB = COALESCE(source.fieldB, YourTable.fieldB);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use 2 separate SQL-statements because the set operator works on the whole resultset that's filtered by the where-clause.

```
UPDATE table SET fieldA='valueA' WHERE id='id1'; UPDATE table SET fieldB='valueB' WHERE id='id2';
```

Answer (score -3):

```
UPDATE table SET fieldA='valueA',fieldB='valueB' WHERE id in ('id1','id2')
```

Comment: This will update both fields for both IDs.  The OP wants a different field update for each ID.