# how to update a column in a table with unique values, but not all the rows, not incremented

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to perform multiple updates with a single UPDATE SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412101/is-it-possible-to-perform-multiple-updates-with-a-single-update-sql-statement)

I am updating a table with some new values for a particular column as below, so i am updating table Prepay, column PrepayTransactionDesc, on certain fows indicated by prepayId

```
update Prepay
set PrepayTransactionDesc = 'Funded Repeat Voucher 153429'
where prepayId = 58045
```

It works fine, but i want to do multiple updates.
I have tried a few different ways but failed. the was i was trying to do it was using CASE when and then.

for instance, i have the following prepayid and prepaytransactiondesc fields

```
57770   Funded Repeat Voucher 153118
57771   Funded Repeat Voucher 153119
57772   Funded Repeat Voucher 153120
57773   Funded Repeat Voucher 153121
57774   Funded Repeat Voucher 153122
57775   Funded Repeat Voucher 153123
57776   Funded Repeat Voucher 153124
57894   Funded Repeat Voucher 153276
57895   Funded Repeat Voucher 153277
57896   Funded Repeat Voucher 153278
```

How would i do them in 1 go? It cant be that difficult but i seem to be missing something when i try to do the task.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? How do you determine the values for each update?

Comment: What do you mean by updating them in 1 go???

Comment: How do you relate the prepayId with the Voucher number?

Comment: @NimChimpsky Although the problem is similar this is clearly another question and the solution to that question might be different to this one as in that question there was a pattern to the replacement.

Comment: @Clodoaldo its identical in all meangiful ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
UPDATE Prepay
SET PrepayTransactionDesc = 
   CASE
     WHEN prepayID = 57770 THEN 'Funded Repeat Voucher 153118'
     WHEN prepayID = 57771 THEN 'Funded Repeat Voucher 153119'
     WHEN prepayID = nextID THEN 'Next Value' 
   END
WHERE  prepayID in (1,2,4,57770... all your ids here)
```

Comment: you could try that, but it doesn't do what is required

Comment: well then I don't understand the question. Explain to me instead to downvoting. I'm here to help

Comment: I think each prepayId will have a different PrepayTransactionDesc

Comment: While this works, it is completely a one-off solution.  Consider if you wanted to use your code again for a totally new set of id/description values.  You'd have to rewrite the entire statement.

Comment: Yeah I know good point to mention, but I kept the same direction as the op were going. You never know, maybe he doesn't have the permission to create tables. So that's another solution

Comment: it worked great, did exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Put your data to update into a temp variable table.  Then join it with the table you want to update in the FROM clause of your update statement.  This will allow you to update multiple rows in one statement.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (id INT, desc VARCHAR(200))
INSERT @data VALUES (57770, 'Funded Repeat Voucher 153118')
INSERT @data VALUES (57771, 'Funded Repeat Voucher 153119')

UPDATE Prepay
SET PrepayTransactionDesc = @data.desc
FROM Prepay
    INNER JOIN @data ON Prepay.prepayID = @data.id
```

Comment: while this works, it is completely a one-off solution. Consider if you wanted to use your code again for a totally new set of id/description values. You'd have to write a whole new set of insert/update statements and you have the extra overhead of creating temp tables.

Comment: The temp table can be built programmatically or passed as a variable to the stored-procedure.

Comment: I'll point out that with all of programming you have to put the data into some sort of structured container in order to work with it.  You can not ever avoid putting these pairs of data into some kind of collection.  Since we are using SQL, a table is the obvious choice because the data coming into this statement, the rows of id/description pairs, are a table.

Answer (score 0):

```
update Prepay
  set PrepayTransactionDesc = 
    case
      when prepayId = 58045 then 'Funded Repeat Voucher 153429'
      when prepayId = 57770 then 'Funded Repeat Voucher 153118'
    end
where
  prepayId in (58045 , 57770)
```

Obviously add the other values

Comment: trying this again, it is pretty similar to what i tried but i had the end in the wrong place!!

Comment: Does it work? Plz give us a feedback

Comment: worked great, similar to first post

Answer (score 0):

```
Update Prepay SET PrepayTransactionDesc = 'Funded Repeat Voucher 153429' WHERE  prepayID  BETWEEN yourid AND yourid
```