# How do we perform multiple updates in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
Table:T1 (key, numval, state) and T2(key, foreignkey:T1.key, type)
```

> I have two tables T1 and T2, for each T1 there are multiple values in
>   T2. And for each value in T2 there is a single value in T1.
>
> Consider that I have two types ('A','B') in T2 and I have to count the number of T2s mapped to each T1 key with the state of 'A' and 'B'and set it to T1.state respectively

**How do I accomplish this in Oracle?**

*Similar to the post below (But the solution does not work):*
[how to update a column in a table with unique values, but not all the rows, not incremented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839835/how-to-update-a-column-in-a-table-with-unique-values-but-not-all-the-rows-not)

Using the source above - I used the following script:

```
UPDATE T1
SET VALUE =
   CASE
     WHEN (SELECT STATE FROM T1 WHERE KEY = EACH_KEY) = 'S1' 
                THEN 
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2 
                                    WHERE KEY = EACH_KEY AND TYPE = 'A' 
     WHEN (SELECT STATE FROM T1 WHERE KEY = EACH_KEY) = 'S2' 
                THEN 
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2 
                                    WHERE KEY = EACH_KEY AND TYPE = 'B' 
   END
WHERE  EACH_KEY in (select distinct KEY from T1);
```

But oracle throws the following error:

```
Error at Command Line : 13 Column : 8
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "EACH_KEY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

EDIT #1:

**SAMPLE DATA in TABLES**

***BEFORE EXECUTION***

```
T1
key    numval    state
1      0         S1
2      0         S2
3      0         S1
4      0         S1

T2
key    t1key     type
1      1         A
2      1         B
3      1         B
4      2         A
5      2         B
6      2         B
7      3         B
8      4         A
9      4         A
10      4         B
```

**AFTER EXECUTION (EXPECTED RESULT)**

```
T1
key    numval    state
1      1         S1
2      2         S2
3      0         S1
4      2         S2
```

EDIT #2:

Yes, the identifier is not defined. I want to know how such an identifier can be defined in Oracle SQL so that the above mentioned calculation can be performed.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question to show some sample data in both tables as well as the output you're expecting. Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714710/add-missing-data-from-previous-month-or-year-cumulatively#36714710) would be good.

Comment: Also, where did the "each_key" come from? The Oracle message is correct; it's not a column in t1 (at least, according to the description of the tables that you provided).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE T1
SET numval = CASE WHEN t1.state = 'S1' THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                             FROM t2
                                             WHERE t1.key = t2.t1key
                                               AND type = 'A')
                  WHEN t1.state = 'S2' THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                             FROM t2
                                             WHERE t1.key = t2.t1key
                                               AND type = 'B')
             END
```

Comment: @NaveenDennis where do you get the idea that to reference the value t2.t1key a join has to be performed? The type of subquery used in Jva's update statement is known as a correlated subquery. If you aren't sure of what that is, you should research it. Jva's answer is correct from what I can see - I'll post a test case in a separate answer to demonstrate, but I came up with the exact same solution as this one, so you should accept the answer to this one.

Comment: @Boneist Yes, I just found out about that. Please do demonstrate it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the test case to support @jva's answer:

**Create the tables with the data:**

```
create table t1 as
select 1 key, 0 numval, 'S1' state from dual union all
select 2 key, 0 numval, 'S2' state from dual union all
select 3 key, 0 numval, 'S1' state from dual union all
select 4 key, 0 numval, 'S1' state from dual;

create table t2 as
select 1 key, 1 t1key, 'A' type from dual union all
select 2 key, 1 t1key, 'B' type from dual union all
select 3 key, 1 t1key, 'B' type from dual union all
select 4 key, 2 t1key, 'A' type from dual union all
select 5 key, 2 t1key, 'B' type from dual union all
select 6 key, 2 t1key, 'B' type from dual union all
select 7 key, 3 t1key, 'B' type from dual union all
select 8 key, 4 t1key, 'A' type from dual union all
select 9 key, 4 t1key, 'A' type from dual union all
select 10 key, 4 t1key, 'B' type from dual;
```

**Check the initial values in t1:**

```
select * from t1 order by key;

       KEY     NUMVAL STATE
---------- ---------- -----
         1          0 S1   
         2          0 S2   
         3          0 S1   
         4          0 S1
```

**Perform the update:**

```
update t1
set    numval = case when state = 'S1' then (select count(*) from t2 where t2.t1key = t1.key and t2.type = 'A')
                     when state = 'S2' then (select count(*) from t2 where t2.t1key = t1.key and t2.type = 'B')
                end;

commit;
```

**Check the new values in t1:**

```
select * from t1 order by key;

       KEY     NUMVAL STATE
---------- ---------- -----
         1          1 S1   
         2          2 S2   
         3          0 S1   
         4          2 S1
```

As you can see, this is the output you wanted.

From the "defects" you mentioned in your comment on @jva's answer, I think you're confused over:

1. the use of the correlated subquery in the answer, and
2. how the update works with a correlated subquery.

I highly recommend you check out [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries007.htm#SQLRF52357), specifically:

> Oracle performs a **correlated subquery** when a nested subquery references a column from a table referred to a parent statement one level above the subquery. The parent statement can be a SELECT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement in which the subquery is nested. A correlated subquery conceptually is evaluated once for each row processed by the parent statement.