# updating a table upon two conditions from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns like `book`, `startyear`, `endyear` and `author`.

I need to update `startyear` and `endyear` columns simultaneously depending on the following conditions,

```
STARTYEAR = ENDYEAR where STARTYEAR=0 and ENDYEAR != 0 
also
ENDYEAR = STARTYEAR  where ENDYEAR =0 and STARTYEAR != 0
```

It is possible with

```
UPDATE Table SET STARTYEAR = ENDYEAR WHERE STARTYEAR=0 AND ENDYEAR<>0; 
UPDATE Table SET ENDYEAR = STARTYEAR  WHERE ENDYEAR =0 AND STARTYEAR<>0;
```

How can I write these 2 queries in a single query?

Answer (score 4):

```
update table
set 
startYear = case when startyear = 0 and endyear<>0 then endyear else startYear end,
endYear = case when endyear = 0 and startyear <> 0 then startyear else endYear end
where startyear = 0 or endyear = 0;
```

Comment: You can just make them bot = 0 since that is the desired result when either is 0

Comment: @Techmonk no, you should re-read the question, the goal is not to set these values to 0.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be:

```
UPDATE Table 
SET STARTYEAR = STARTYEAR + ENDYEAR
  , ENDYEAR   = STARTYEAR + ENDYEAR
WHERE STARTYEAR = 0 AND ENDYEAR <> 0
   OR ENDYEAR = 0 AND STARTYEAR <> 0 ;
```

But I really don't see any reasons for doing this. You can use the 2-statements way you have, inside a transaction. It may even be more efficient than any convoluted single statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use or and update bot fields unless you have triggers stopping you from doing this for cases where startyear = endyear = 0;

```
UPDATE Table SET STARTYEAR = STARTYEAR+ ENDYEAR, ENDYEAR = STARTYEAR+ENDYEAR WHERE STARTYEAR=0 OR ENDYEAR=0
```

Comment: +1, smart and easy idea. The only risk is  null values :  startYear = 0, endYear IS NULL so 0 + NULL = NULL, not 0. Just add a coalesce  and it will be fine (if they are nullable).

Answer (score 0):

You can't update multiple tables in one statement, however, you can use a transaction to make sure that two UPDATE statements are treated like one. You can also batch them to avoid a round trip.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE Table SET STARTYEAR = ENDYEAR WHERE STARTYEAR=0 AND ENDYEAR<>0; 

UPDATE Table SET ENDYEAR = STARTYEAR  WHERE ENDYEAR =0 AND STARTYEAR<>0;

COMMIT
```

but in your case you can also use something like the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412101/is-it-possible-to-perform-multiple-updates-with-a-single-update-sql-statement).

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
update test
   set startyear = (case when startyear = 0 AND endyear <> 0 then endyear else startyear end),
       endyear   = (case when endyear = 0 AND startyear <> 0 then startyear else endyear end);
```