# How can i combine multiple queries in one? Instead of running them 1 by 1?

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Table].[Rating] = 'A-'
WHERE ((([Table].[Field1])<>'No'
And     ([Table].[Field2])<>'No')
AND    (([Table].[Field3])<>'No')
AND    (([Table].[Field4])<>'No')


UPDATE [Table] SET [Table].[Rating] = 'B'
WHERE ((([Table].[Field1])<>'No'
And     ([Table].[Field2])<>'No')
AND    (([Table].[Field3])<>'No')
AND    (([Table].[Field4])='No')

UPDATE [Table] SET [Table].[Rating] = 'C'
WHERE ((([Table].[Field1])<>'No'
And     ([Table].[Field2])<>'No')
AND    (([Table].[Field3])='No')
AND    (([Table].[Field4])='No')

UPDATE [Table] SET [Table].[Rating] = 'D'
WHERE ((([Table].[Field1])<>'No'
And     ([Table].[Field2])='No')
AND    (([Table].[Field3])='No')
AND    (([Table].[Field4])='No')
```

Comment: Do you mean you want 1 Query that would achieve the same result or do you mean that you want to run more than one.

Comment: i'm running them one by one for ratings, and how can i run them all in one?

Comment: Edward is this being done in a stored procedure?

Comment: Why not consider using and `If/THEN` `else/If` type of statement. As long as its in one stored procedure you can basically say `if this field(s) = something than do something`...

Comment: You need to provide some context. What is the use case? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Just trying to update Field Rating A B C or D based on Yes NO Answers in other fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE Table SET Table.[Rating] = 'A-'
WHERE (((Table.[Field1])<>'No' And (Table.[Field2]))<>'No') And ((Table.[Field3]))<>'No') And ((Table.[Field4])<>'No'));

Answer (score 2):

See whether you can use an `UPDATE` with a [Switch](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) statement to assign the `Rating` value based on your criteria.

```sql
UPDATE [Table] AS t
SET t.[Rating] = 
    Switch
        (
            t.Field2 <> 'No' AND t.Field3 <> 'No' AND t.Field4 <> 'No', 'A',
            t.Field2 <> 'No' AND t.Field3 <> 'No' AND t.Field4 =  'No', 'B',
            t.Field2 <> 'No' AND t.Field3 =  'No' AND t.Field4 =  'No', 'C',
            t.Field2 =  'No' AND t.Field3 =  'No' AND t.Field4 =  'No', 'D'
        )
WHERE
        t.Field1 <> 'No';
```

Comment: Ok, if all the 4 Fields <> NO then Rated A, if 3 Fields <> NO and 1 Field =No then Rated B, and so on.

Comment: OK, it seems "t.Field1 <> 'No'" is common to all four cases, so I put that in the `WHERE` clause and used the other 3 column conditions in the `Switch` expression.

Comment: Oops, looking at the SQL in your question again, I'm doubting I got it right.  But hopefully it's close enough for you to refine.

Comment: i don't need you to do my work :) i just wanted the syntax, thnx, i'll try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this answer should help, using a temp table:  [Multiple Updates in One SQL Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412101/is-it-possible-to-perform-multiple-updates-with-a-single-update-sql-statement)

However, I don't see any differences in your WHERE clauses, between the 4 values you are updating to.  Is that correct?

Comment: I'm Updating Field Rating A or B or C or D based on other fields info.