# MySQL Table won't update multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I am not sure, but I think I have an error in this query:

```
UPDATE product_discount SET price = '10,15' WHERE key_id = '1,2'
```

I can't figure out why, but it only updates number 10 in the column and skips the 15.

Comment: whats the datatype of price ?

Comment: What's the data type for the `price` column?

Comment: @Kermit sorry it is DECIMAL

Comment: no. It has to be one row with id 1 have 10 and row two with id 2 have 15

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Updates in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql)

Comment: So you're trying to update two rows, the one with id 1 to 10, the one with id 2 to 15?

Comment: http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/  Great question.  I think others will learn about updating multiple rows with different values in a single query based on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the method suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3466/2359271):

```
INSERT INTO product_discount (key_id, price) 
VALUES (1, 10), (2, 15)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price=VALUES(price);
```

Be sure to read the linked answer for some caveats, though; for example, this only works if:

- There is a unique key constraint on `key_id` (e.g., it is the primary key)
- You know that the rows with these ids already exist, or you don't mind inserting new rows if you provide an id that doesn't exist in the table

---

Despite these limitations on its use, the significant advantage of this method over `CASE` statements is much better readability and parameterization. In Python, for example, here's how you would execute the query given in @Kaf's answer using the `MySQLdb` module:

```
query = """UPDATE product_discount SET price = CASE 
    WHEN key_id = %s THEN %s ELSE %s 
    END 
WHERE ID IN (%s, %s);"""

params = (1, 10, 15, 1, 2)

cursor.execute(query, params)
```

How long is it going to take someone to figure out from that `params` tuple which values you want updated, and what their values should be? And what if you want to update more than two rows? Not only do you need to rewrite `query` for every use case of N rows, the `params` tuple becomes indecipherable garbage if N is anything more than a handful. You could write some helper functions to format both `query` and `params` according to the number of updates you need to do, but how long will that take? How easy will it be to understand? How many opportunities for bugs will you introduce in all these extra lines of code?

On the other hand, here's how you would do it using the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` method:

```
query = """INSERT INTO product_discount (key_id, price) VALUES (%s, %s)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price=VALUES(price);"""
params = [(1, 10),
          (2, 15),
          ]
cursor.executemany(query, params)
```

The key-value relationship is clear and highly readable. If more rows need to be updated, more key-value tuples can be added to the params list. It's not a perfect solution for every scenario, but it's a much better solution than `CASE` for particular (and I would argue, *very* common) scenarios.

Comment: @xQbert It's an `INSERT` statement, but an update method nonetheless. I've added some detail re: when and why you might prefer it over the `UPDATE ... CASE` method.

Comment: Missed the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price=VALUES(price);` initially.  +1 for the follow through and more detail.  The risk I see with this is if someone passes in the wrong parameters, you may end up updating an existing record when you really meant to create one; and no error would be thrown.  While readability may improve, some environments may struggle with writing an insert statement for an update.  but since the developer should see the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE price=VALUES(price);`  risk is mitigated. to a degree.

Comment: I think I would agree that the `UPDATE ... CASE` method is safer, in so far as can be made brutally explicit. The best thing would obviously be a supported syntax for multiple updates in MySQL.

Comment: For that matter, [using a mapping table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/412323/2359271) is probably the safest and most scalable method, at the expense of requiring several extra steps.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you need (Assuming `Price` should be 10 when `key_id = 1`):

```
UPDATE product_discount SET price = CASE WHEN key_id = 1 THEN 10 ELSE 15 END
WHERE key_id IN (1,2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure a `CASE` is required in there.

Comment: If OP needs different values for `Price` depending on `key_id` then we need a CASE expression, otherwise not. As per his/her comments, I think OP needs 10 for key_id = 1.

Comment: @Kaf, Your answer is great, I will do the same but I think the last WHERE part is not needed.

Comment: This works for the specific case OP is asking about but it might be better to use explicit cases for each row that should be updated, instead of `ELSE 15`, in case novices don't immediately see how to extend this to update >2 rows. (Case in point: @Rahul's comment above...)

Answer (score 1):

I think Kaf was close, but there are times where key_id can be 3 or 4 or 5 right?  So you need to make sure those values don't change to 15.  This should do the trick!

```
UPDATE product_discount 
SET price = CASE WHEN key_id = 1 THEN 10 
                 WHEN key_id = 2 THEN 15 
                 ELSE price END
```

Comment: Kaf is already correct, since rows with key_id other than 1 and 2 won't be updated.

Comment: Actually, you're right.  Because there is a where clause for just the 1 and 2, it should work.

Comment: This should work too, but I suspect if you have a few million rows, his will update only the rows necessary while this will update _all_ rows.

Answer (score 1):

I feel what you are trying to do is

> update price = 10 when key_id = 1
>   (OR)
>   price=15 when key_id = 2.

In that case just do it like

```
UPDATE product_discount SET price = 
CASE WHEN key_id = 1 THEN 10 
WHEN key_id = 2 THEN 15
ELSE price
END
```

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, My Bad totally. Thanks for pointing me the error. Update the answer and fiddle together.

Comment: This should work, but I suspect if you have a few million rows, Kaf's answer will update only the rows necessary while this will update _all_ rows (or at least not use an index to find the rows to update)

Comment: So what will be the actual answer then @JoachimIsaksson cause I need it so much

Comment: @user3465207, I feel Kafs answer would be just fine for what you are asking. Only difference b/w Kaff's and my answer is the where clause. You can use the fiddle mentioned in this comment chain for testing purpose.