# I want to create single query for this multiple queries

Tags: sql

```
Update TransactionsMovs SET SubNumId='5253420' where SubNumId='3014362178619A000000033F' and CustNumKey='0024180002'
Update TransactionsMovs SET SubNumID='5253416' where SubNumId='301402662C2DC5800000017C' and CustNumKey='0024180003' 
Update TransactionsMovs SET SubNumID='5253419' where SubNumId='301402662C42F480000036AF' and CustNumKey='0024180004'
Update TransactionsMovs SET SubNumID='5253418' where SubNumId='30143639F809E880000003AA' and ItemNumKey='055270490-32-30'
Update TransactionsMovs SET SubNumID='5253417' where SubNumId='30140BA4EC4833C00000008C' and CustNumKey='0022870002'
```

Comment: You're updating different keys with different fields, why would you merrge this into 1 query? What's the benifit of that?

Comment: You cannot.....

Comment: try using case...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to perform multiple updates with a single UPDATE SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412101/is-it-possible-to-perform-multiple-updates-with-a-single-update-sql-statement)

Comment: Please explain your  requirement in details.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to reduce database round trip ?
If yes you can just surround query with begin end;

```
BEGIN
    Update TransactionsMovs SET SubNumId='5253420' where SubNumId='3014362178619A000000033F' and CustNumKey='0024180002';
    Update TransactionsMovs SET SubNumID='5253416' where SubNumId='301402662C2DC5800000017C' and CustNumKey='0024180003';
    Update TransactionsMovs SET SubNumID='5253419' where SubNumId='301402662C42F480000036AF' and CustNumKey='0024180004';
    Update TransactionsMovs SET SubNumID='5253418' where SubNumId='30143639F809E880000003AA' and ItemNumKey='055270490-32-30';
    Update TransactionsMovs SET SubNumID='5253417' where SubNumId='30140BA4EC4833C00000008C' and CustNumKey='0022870002';
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying achieve something like this, combining all condition with one UPDATE statement.

```
Update TransactionsMovs
SET    SubNumId = CASE WHEN SubNumId='3014362178619A000000033F' AND CustNumKey='0024180002' THEN '5253420' 
                       WHEN SubNumId='301402662C2DC5800000017C' AND CustNumKey='0024180003' THEN '5253416' 
                       WHEN SubNumId='301402662C42F480000036AF' AND CustNumKey='0024180004' THEN '5253419' 
                       WHEN SubNumId='30143639F809E880000003AA' AND ItemNumKey='055270490-32-30' THEN '5253418'
                       WHEN SubNumId='30140BA4EC4833C00000008C' AND CustNumKey='0022870002' THEN '5253417'         
          END
```